# Measure Unit Test coverage of specific files with Py.Test

Tags: python, code-coverage, pytest

I'm trying to retrieve the coverage of my unittests with Py.Test. The problem is that I get also coverage information about other python files which I don't care about.

Here is an example of my file structure. In this case I want to test: **car.py, wheel.py and steer.py**

**python2.7/site-packages/**

- car.py
- wheel.py
- steer.py
- coverage.py (from pypi.python.org)
- yaml (the python yaml library, from pypi.python.org)
- pytest-2.5.2-py2.7.egg (the python py.test library)
- and many more

**python2.7/site-packages/test/**

- test_car.py
- conftest.py

Now I use Py.Test to execute the test:

```
python -m pytest --cov python2.7/site-packages/ python2.7/site-packages/test/test_car.py
```

But this results in the coverage of all the python files in site-packages (kinda obvious).

```
python -m pytest --cov python2.7/site-packages/car.py python2.7/site-packages/test/test_car.py
```

This results in only the coverage of the car.py and not all the files I want.

How can I use Py.Test to only to measure coverage of specific files?

(I also tried:

```
python -m pytest --cov python2.7/site-packages/car.py,python2.7/site-packages/wheel.py python2.7/site-packages/test/test_car.py
```

But Py.Test doesn't know how to parse and use this argument.
)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the solution. You can supply multiple `--cov file` arguments.

```sh
python -m pytest \
  --cov python2.7/site-packages/car.py \
  --cov python2.7/site-packages/wheel.py \
  --cov python2.7/site-packages/steer.py \
  python2.7/site-packages/test/test_car.py
```

Comment: @Tengis: while you can, it's not recommended - a solved question should have an answer, search won't find it otherwise

Comment: It doesn't seem to honor that flag, I still get a report for my whole project instead of the single file I pass.

Comment: Try the module import name, not the file name.  --cov=package.module